# Are hyperlinks supported in IRC chat?

Tags: hyperlink, irc

Are hyperlinks supported in IRC chat? I've tried using the standard hyperlink formats, but none of them seem to render as expected:

- Markdown: `[Super User](https://superuser.com/)`
- Wikitext: `[https://superuser.com/ Super User]`
- HTML: `<a href="https://superuser.com/">Super User</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no special codes to make a link with optional text. Posting a link itself may or may not be clickable.

It depends on the irc client of the user. To some it will be text only and they have to copy it and paste it in their browser.

Other clients will convert it to a hyperlink and the user can then click the link.